# How to set allowed lateness for late data and discard all data after that lateness period in java Apache beam dataflow windows?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to have a window of 1 minute, with allowed lateness of 2 minutes and I want to discard all other data incoming after that time.

I could set the allowed lateness, but the data that comes after all the windows and lateness is triggering the window more times. The late data is emitted as pane in addition to the normal data. I want only one pane per window, discarding the late data.

Right now having this code:

```
        Window<KV<String, Measurement>> window = Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(DOWNSAMPLING_PERIOD_SECONDS)));


    if (this.ALLOWED_LATENESS_SECONDS != null) {
        Trigger customTrigger = AfterWatermark
                .pastEndOfWindow()
                .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                        .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(ALLOWED_LATENESS_SECONDS)));
        window = window
                .triggering(customTrigger)

                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(ALLOWED_LATENESS_SECONDS), Window.ClosingBehavior.FIRE_ALWAYS)
                .discardingFiredPanes();
```

Comment: You can allow late data by invoking the .withAllowedLateness operation .It defines how long the late date will be accepted and also how long the state of the old window will be kept alive.Do these [link1](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Window.html), [link2](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-beam/late-data-apache-beam/read#:\~:text=Apache%20Beam%20provides%20a%20mechanism,This%20mechanism%20is%20called%20watermark) and [link3](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#window-accumulation-modes) help you?

Comment: @kiranmathew I have already enabled withAllowedLateness, as you can see in my code, The problem is that there are multiple panes emmited by the same window. I want to avoid that. There should be always only one pane per window. Everything else should be discarded

Comment: This [document](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/PaneInfo.Timing.html) discusses multiple pane fire. Does this document help you?<br>

Comment: @kiranmathew
I read a lot. But this page is new for me. Will try out. thx.